# Transforming Coordinates From ETRS89 into WGS84 has an 0.5m error. (Projected coordinates)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.5

Original post had to do with software or OS bug.

---

But when working with coordinates in ETRS89 (projected data), I was facing an issue in centimeter value when I transformed the data into UTM. My result had an 0.5m error after conversion. I'm using coordinates frame (7 parameters) for creating the Geographic Transformation.
Than i remembered than i had created a thread about an issue in Geographic Transformation and an ESRI employee replayed by suggesting me to transform geographic coordinates than to project into a projected coordinate system.

By following this instruction my converted data have no errors.

Comment: Please always include errors as text so that they can be searched by others with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an oversight when we originally designed the tool. It was, and is, meant to define a geographic/datum transformation between two geographic coordinate reference systems. The input and output coordinate reference systems cannot be projected coordinate reference systems.

I don't remember which release, but we blocked it. Even if you put in a projected coordinate reference system, we extract the geographic coordinate reference system and use that instead.

The change happened a while ago--10.3.1 or maybe 10.4.

The transformation methods that this tool uses are all designed to convert between latitude-longitude values, not projected values. I'm surprised that it ever worked. If you know all this, and really are trying to convert between Pulkovo 1942 and WGS 1984, try recreating the transformation but give the GeoCRS definitions as the input/output coordinate systems instead.

Disclosure: Esri employee

Comment: I came back to thank you, you reply did not solved directly the issue. However I remembered that once an esri employee suggested me to use the project tool only for geographic coordinates because they has blocked this tool for projected coordinates (even the tool may run and sometimes its result fulfills the requirements). Just had an issue with result in centimeter value and solved it only because i remembered your reply. THNX

Comment: Thank you very much! If you want, you could edit the answer to include that information or add your own answer. Comments sometimes get deleted. Anyway, Project Tool should work with projected coordinates, no problem!